# Did the Troll intend UK-Argentine war?

Tags: apocalypse-troll

In Chapter 14 of "Apocalypse Troll", M&M has difficulties getting to Scotland, because the UK got into a shooting war with Argentineans, which it is alleged is a direct result of Troll's earlier actions in Chapter 13:

> Their original plan to fly out on an Air Force B-1B scheduled for a training mission to Britain had been scrubbed **when the South Atlantic suddenly turned hot**. Morris shook his head sadly, wondering what had gone wrong. He had many contacts in the Royal Navy, and **he'd been positive the Brits contemplated no offensive action. But something had hit the fan down there, and the Argentinean charges of unprovoked attacks and the massacre and mutilation of prisoners sounded ugly, indeed**. It was too bad the US hadn't had a recon bird up to see what was going on for itself, but it appeared that the first the Brits knew of it had been a sudden, totally unexpected strike on one of their LPH assault ships by a quartet of the Mirage 2000-5s which had finally replaced the venerable Super Étendards as Argentina's primary launch platform for the Exocet.

Obviously, this caused extra difficulties for anti-Troll humans (and later in the book - spoiler - required the US to exert pressure to stop that war). But **was this South Atlantic war Troll's explicit goal, or was it just an unplanned side effect of his interrogation of Argentinean personnel**?

Comment: This doesn't affect my answer, but I would disagree that the UK-Argentina war "caused extra difficulties" (well, apart from M&M's trip). It was actually quite handy for the US, as it gave a pretext for shufflling around military personnel to put telepathically-vulnerable soldiers in non-critical posts.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - it also have President an exuse to roofie Russian Ambassador to take his EKG :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is little doubt that the Troll had no interest in starting a war between the UK and Argentina, and this was an accidental side-effect of the raid it made on an Argentinian radar post which was wrongly blamed on the British.

The Troll had landed in Antartica and was moving cautiously northward to investigate its surroundings. There was an already-existing tension between Argentina and the UK - "both sides glared at one another through the invisible beams of their radar installations" - but it is explicitly stated that:

> The Troll had neither known nor cared why there was so much electronic
> activity. It was simply one more problem to be dealt with...

When he ransacked the mind of Captain Santiago before killing him and his troops on the radar base, the Troll did acquire information about the international tension

> Troll considered the fragmentary information he’d gleaned. He had only
> a vague notion of who these "British" enemies of the captain were, but
> he had learned enough to be disinterested in them

but clearly regarded it as being of little importance. What *was* of importance was the location of the USA (and its nuclear arsenal), which informed the next moves in his plans. So far from fanning the UK-Argentina war, the Troll seems completely uninterested in it.

Later in the book we see how the Troll revels in the deaths of humans in conflicts that it stirs up. The absence of any joy produced by the UK-Argentina war (until the US intervened to end it) again indicates that the Troll was not involved.